# Titanium/ Appcelerator Alloy not detecting orientation change correctly

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, titanium-alloy

I have some bizarre behaviour when detecting orientation using titanium.

### Code

This is the code I am using on `index.js`:

```
// Start code
Ti.API.info('Orientation: ' + Ti.Gesture.orientation);
Ti.API.info('Portrait: ' + Ti.Gesture.portrait);
Ti.API.info('Landscape: ' + Ti.Gesture.landscape);
Ti.API.info(Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth + ' x ' + Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformHeight);

// Code when orientation changes
Ti.Gesture.addEventListener('orientationchange',function(e) {
    Ti.API.info('orientation changed!');
    Ti.API.info('Orientation: ' + e.orientation);
    Ti.API.info('Portrait: ' + e.source.isPortrait());
    Ti.API.info('Landscape: ' + e.source.isLandscape());
    Ti.API.info(Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth + ' x ' + Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformHeight);    
});
```

### Initial

- I am using the Andriod Emulater with the Nexus 6.
- I'm starting off the app at `0 degrees` (normal portrait position).

I get the following output when the program starts:

```
Orientation: 1        (Same as Ti.UI.PORTRAIT)
Portrait: true
Landscape: false
1440 x 2392
```

### 90 degrees

Upon rotating the phone in the `90 degrees` position, the event is not even triggered! **Why not?**

### 180 degrees

Rotating it clockwise again to the `180 degrees` position does trigger the event and gives the following correct values on the console:

```
orientation changed!
Orientation: 4         (Same as Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_RIGHT)
Portrait: false
Landscape: true
2392 x 1440
```

*(Note that even though the phone is technically in portrait, the app shows up in landscape as the phone is the wrong way round. This is expected Android behaviour)*

### 270 degrees

Rotating it clockwise again to the `270 degrees` positions triggers the event and gives the following correct values:

```
orientation changed!
Orientation: 4         (Same as Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_RIGHT. Should be Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_LEFT?)
Portrait: false
Landscape: true
2392 x 1440
```

### 0 degrees

However, when rotating clockwise again (back to `0 degrees`) I get the incorrect values:

```
orientation changed!
Orientation: 2         (Same as Ti.UI.UPSIDE_PORTRAIT)
Portrait: false
Landscape: true
2392 x 1440
```

Note how:

- It claims to be in landscape mode when it should be in portrait
- The `e.orientation` seems to give semi-correct result of `Ti.UI.UPSIDE_PORTRAIT` when it should be `Ti.UI.PORTRAIT`. No biggie.
- The width and height has been flipped (probably because it thinks it's still in landscape)!

### Questions

1. Why is the first rotation not triggering the event!
2. Why is the last rotation showing incorrect values for ALL the values.

Answer (score 3):

Inside the `orientationchange` listener it's probably better if you check the `e.orientation` and you compare it with the normal orientation constants (`Ti.UI.PORTRAIT, Ti.UI.UPSIDE_PORTRAIT, Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_LEFT, Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_RIGHT`).

This because there are other orientations too (`FACE_DOWN, FACE_UP`) and once I got crazy trying to understand why some of my customers sometimes noticed some "flickering" (the moving from `FACE_DOWN` to `FACE_UP`).

Moreover: test your listener with a **real device** because testing `orientationchange` event in a emulator is almost completely useless.

Comment: That doesn't explain why the event is not even triggered on the first rotation. It also doesn't explain why the width and height are the wrong way round on the last rotation.

Comment: @YahyaUddin just do an attempt and try what I've suggested you. Forget about isPortrait and isLandscape methods.

Comment: But I already have. See the question. It's the 2nd line on the event handler just under `Ti.API.info('orientation changed!');`. I've also edited the question to make this more clearer. This doesn't change the fact that the event does not even trigger on the first rotation!

Comment: @YahyaUddin I've never had this problem so I don't know, but before deleting my answer I suggest you to test your orientationchange listener with a physical device because otherwise it's impossible to discover bugs caused by orientations not available on emulators.

Comment: hmmm it seems to work well on a real device. Must be an issue with an emulator.  How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you have the same issue when running the above program on a Nexus 6 Virtual Device?

Comment: @YahyaUddin I've tried with some emulators but after I discovered the problem with FACE_DOWN-FACE_UP orientations I gave up and I worked on these kind of problems only with physical devices. I don't know about Nexus 6 emulator.

Comment: I've found this issue with ANY device on the official Android AVD emulator. Do you mind to just test it out to see if you get the same issue?

Comment: Sorry but at the moment I'm not developing a lot on Titanium, and I avoid android emulators like a plague (specially on Titanium) so I cannot test it.